# How do I validate the input field values which should contain integers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have `<div>` elements like below:

```
<div>
<div class="x"><input type="text" name="name1" value="" /> </div>
<div class="x"><input type="text" name="name2" value="" /> </div>
<div class="x"><input type="text" name="name3" value="" /> </div>
<div class="x"><input type="text" name="name4" value="" /> </div>
</div>
```

I want to check that the value is an integer, and if not, display the invalid ones'
user types into those fields, which should not have any submit or button.

Please, can anyone give the solution soon. I wanted use jQuery.

Comment: Doesn't look like homework, but you could at least tried something first

Comment: Just in case you're curious, it's considered bad form to ask a question before at least trying to solve it a little bit on your own. Next time, post some things you've tried (even if you got nowhere) and you'll avoid the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function validate(obj) {
   if (obj.value.match(/[^0-9]/) {
      ... entered non-integer
   } else {
      ... looks ok
   }
}

<input type="text" name="name1" onchange="validate(this)" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

a combination of parseInt() and isNaN() would do it.